# jquery fade in at same time as fade out

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm stuck and I really don't udnerstand jQuery right now!

I want my 3 blocks to fade in a fade out with 3 second delay, in a loop.

This works but I want block 1 to fade out WHILST block 2 is fading in, and not afterwards.

And block 2 to fade out WHILST block 3 is fading in ... and so on!

```
$(".block2").fadeTo("fast", 0.3)
$(".block3").fadeTo("fast", 0.3)

function1();

var timing = 3000;

function function1(){
$(".block1").fadeTo("slow", 1).delay(timing).fadeTo("slow", 0.3, function2);
}

function function2(){
$(".block2").fadeTo("slow", 1).delay(timing).fadeTo("slow", 0.3, function3);
}

function function3(){
$(".block3").fadeTo("slow", 1).delay(timing).fadeTo("slow", 0.3, function1);
}
```

Thank you =)

Comment: [Can you make a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: If you want animations to happen concurrently, start them all one after the other. Callbacks aren't called until the animation completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give all your blocks a common `.block`

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/idozey/7/edit)

```
var el = $('.block'),
    F = 800,   // FADE TIME
    P = 3000,  // PAUSE TIME
    S = -1;    // START el index (will turn 0 after initial kick)
    
function a(){el.eq(++S%el.length).fadeTo(F,1).siblings(el).stop(1).fadeTo(F,0.3);}
a();

setInterval(a, P);
```

Comment: Can you explain this piece please: `(S=++S%el.length)`?

Comment: @Fresheyeball ++S is an pre incremented counter. Modulo prevents S to turn S into an unexistant `.eq( index )` number element. That means that after each loop id does: "**set (correct if needed) S to a preincr.S%3**" (if 3 is the returned length). keep in mind that 3%3 == 0 :) and voila! the 0 indexed element will fade.

Comment: You just blew my mind with modulo. I've never used it in that way. Last question. Why the `S=` wouldn't `(++S%el.length)` work fine?

Comment: Works perfectly and so simple (even though I don't understand it at all!) - Thanks =)

Comment: @Fresheyeball sure it will, I actually did a mistake. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @roXon ok modulos rules. I feel like I really learned something.

Comment: @Fresheyeball sure they rule! just a little % and you have a loop :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using callbacks. Callbacks wont occurring until the fade out is finished. But we can use a timeout to call both at the same time.

```
$(".block2").fadeTo("fast", 0.3)
$(".block3").fadeTo("fast", 0.3)

function1();

var timing = 3000;

function function1(){
    $(".block1").fadeTo("slow", 1, function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
             function2();
         }, timing);
    }).delay(timing).fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

}
```

Or curry style:

```
var function1, function2, function3;

function1 = fadeInnyOuty( $('.block1'), function2);
function2 = fadeInnyOuty( $('.block2'), function3);
function3 = fadeInnyOuty( $('.block3'), function1);

function fadeInnyOuty($elem,func){
    $elem.fadeTo("slow", 1, function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
             func();
             $elem.fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are triggering the next step using the callback function of the fadeOut action. So the next fadeIn happens after the fadeOut has completed. Instead you want the fadeIn to occur after the delay. You can use the `queue` method to achieve this:

```
.delay(timing).queue(function() {
  function2();
  $(this).dequeue(); // Keeps the queue running, it stops if you don't do this
}).fadeOut("slow", 0.3);
```

I have created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/e8W5E/ to show it in action

---

**Edit** In response to roXon's comments, you could write the solution to be more elegant as follows. The HTML is updated to remove the redundant count...

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

The jQuery then looks like...

```
$(function() {

  // These are the elements we will rotate
  var $blocks = $(".block");

  // Set up the initial elements to 0.3 opacity
  $blocks.not(":eq(0)").fadeTo("fast", 0.3);

  // This is our repeating function
  var go = function($el, i, high, low, t) {
    $el.eq(i).fadeTo("slow", high)
      .delay(t)
      .queue(function() {

        // The next index is 1 + the current index
        // use modulus to repeat back to the beginning
        var next = (i + 1) % $el.length;
        go($el, next, high, low, t);
        $(this).dequeue();
       })
       .fadeTo("slow", low);
  };

  // Start fading in and out
  go($blocks, 0, 1, 0.3, 1000);

})();
```

You can add as many blocks as you like with that class name and it will be included in the fadeIn and fadeOut rotation. And fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8W5E/1/

Comment: I'm sorry, but i think your code is a redundant and bad example of a non-programmatic way to achieve such a simple task. Imagine I have 100's of .block elements, I'd call you to write it for me :)

Comment: @roXon, thanks for the redundant bit of advice there. I had kept the majority of the code the same as the OP to avoid over complicating the advice to fix the actual problem. Yes you can write something much more concise and dynamic but not without also having to explain that as well...